GAE on java 21 throws NullPointerException at CookieCache.parseCookies()
I updated my Google App Engine app from java 17 to java 21
following instructions on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/upgrade-java-runtime
I am using the legacy bundled services.
It appeared to work fine yesterday, but today all requests fail with this in the logs:
writeError: status=500, message=java.lang.NullPointerException, response=org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletContextResponse@7abe8062
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.CookieCache.parseCookies(CookieCache.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.CookieCache.getCookies(CookieCache.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getCookies(Request.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(AbstractSessionManager.java:1231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:851)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ee10.AppEngineWebAppContext.handle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HotSwapHandler.handle(HotSwapHandler.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Wrapper.handle(Handler.java:740)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.CoreSizeLimitHandler.handle(CoreSizeLimitHandler.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpChannelState$HandlerInvoker.run(HttpChannelState.java:635)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.delegate.internal.DelegateConnection.lambda$handle$0(DelegateConnection.java:145)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter$2.run(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:142)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.delegate.internal.DelegateConnection.handle(DelegateConnection.java:141)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.delegate.DelegateConnector.service(DelegateConnector.java:49)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:274)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchServletRequest(RequestRunner.java:348)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchRequest(RequestRunner.java:233)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.run(RequestRunner.java:199)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

There's no direct calls from my codebase in this stacktrace so I'm not sure where to fix it.

Please edit the question by sharing detailed steps along with minimal code and app.yaml file that anyone can use to replicate the behavior? Additionally it would be helpful if you share the entire stack trace?  Also make sure the java version is compatible with its dependencies.

I was experiencing the same problem that requests with cookies failed on Java21.
After trying several things forth and back, it suddenly started working, also with my original version.
I had opened a support case with Google, and I asked the support representative if any changes had been made recently on the AppEngine side, and she was able to confirm that:
"During my investigation, I discovered an internal rollout that occurred around August 23rd. These rollouts can take time to propagate through our system. Given the similarities in the behavior described, it's likely that this rollout may have contributed to the resolution of the behavior you reported."
So if you have been experiencing problems with cookies and Java21, just try again now!

Chiming in here to say I'm seeing the same issue as well. My stack trace is slightly different since I'm using the <property name="appengine.use.EE8" value="true"/> system property in the appenengine-web.xml file. If I remove setting of any cookies the issue goes away.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.CookieCache.parseCookies(CookieCache.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.CookieCache.getCookies(CookieCache.java:71)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getCookies(Request.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(AbstractSessionManager.java:1231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.SessionHandler$CoreSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(SessionHandler.java:637)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:448)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:823)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1421)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler$CoreContextHandler$CoreToNestedHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:2365)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1060)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HotSwapHandler.handle(HotSwapHandler.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Wrapper.handle(Handler.java:740)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.CoreSizeLimitHandler.handle(CoreSizeLimitHandler.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpChannelState$HandlerInvoker.run(HttpChannelState.java:648)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.delegate.internal.DelegateConnection.lambda$handle$0(DelegateConnection.java:145)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter$2.run(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:140)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.delegate.internal.DelegateConnection.handle(DelegateConnection.java:141)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.delegate.DelegateConnector.service(DelegateConnector.java:49)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:274)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchServletRequest(RequestRunner.java:349)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchRequest(RequestRunner.java:234)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.run(RequestRunner.java:200)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

The sourceLocation in the Logs Explorer includes the following:
sourceLocation: {
  file: "HttpChannel.java"
  function: "org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.handleException"
  line: "657"
}

As an experiment I took Google's appengine-java17-bundled-services sample app, changed the runtime to java21, added the setting of a cookie, and did not see the same issue.
I will continue to experiment and will report back if I find a solution.
Update: I was able to track down the source of the issue which was that there was a cookie being set whose value contains a comma. Once that comma was removed everything started working. I was also able to reproduce the issue in the Google sample app by setting a cookie whose value contains a comma and then making a call to HttpServletRequest#getCookies.
